# Is it possible to revisit skipped reviews?

Tags: support, review-queues

On Lifehacks SE I've got the privilege to review, but from time to time I want to postpone or wait a little before doing the actual review of some of the items in the review queue. Therefore I press <kbd>Skip</kbd>, but this hides them (from me, at least).

Is there an option to make skipped items reappear in my review queue?

According to [Can our Review History also list the items we have skipped?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/234909/286540), it is possible to *list* the skipped items. And [Let me review my “skipped” items when I reach the end of the Review queue after skipping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/153451/286540) indicates that this might be possible for the *closed post* queue.

But I can't see this option anywhere, on neither the *closed post* queue or any of the other queues. So, is it possible to revisit skipped items, or make them reappear in my review queue?

Comment: It exists. Go to review/history, scroll to the bottom, and click "show skipped reviews". You should end up on a page with a url like this: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/history?skipped=true

Comment: @NightShadeQueen, I can see them,  but I what to review them. Is that possible?

Comment: I've found that if you click the link that says "Skip" and the review is not currently complete, you can review the review.

Comment: @holroy it is generally unlikely that review on SO will stay incomplete for long time (except close vote queue), so realistically you have only one chance to influence reviews for each item.

Comment: As stated in question this is related to Lifehacks SE,  where the is not so much traffic.

Comment: If this is mostly related to Lifehacks SE, is there any reason to not post the question on Meta Lifehacks? If you ask here, we'll answer you as if you are asking about Stack Overflow, although I don't think there's much difference in this case.

Comment: You can bookmark the current page, hit "Skip", and later return to the bookmark and see if it is still reviewable.

Comment: @mmking, I was aiming for Meta Stack Exchange , to get a broader group, but I sometimes mix that and Meta Stack Overflow. :-)

Comment: I usually hit the back button if I change my mind right after skipping one, and it still lets me take an action on it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Click on recent reviews of the queue you want to see the skipped review(s) of:

[image]

Click on "history"

[image]

Scroll down and make sure "show skipped reviews" is checked, if not click on it to check it.

[image]

Then click on the "skip" on the same row of the review you want to see.

This will bring you to that review you previously skipped. If it's still active (not completed or removed from the queue) then you will still be able to act on it other than skip or even choose skip again if you'd like.

There is no option to re-add skipped reviews you've done in the past to the queue again for you to review normally. Maybe you could start a feature-request if you'd like that option. I certainly wouldn't want to use it since I skip more reviews than all other actions combined (pretty sure of that).

<sup>photos taken from previous answer of mine [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263808/244519)</sup>