# Is it possible to redo an edit review?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

I recently reviewed an item containing a link edit, that looked correct to me. Then I revisited the link itself, and found it wasn't quite right - in fact, the URL in question no longer led to the PDF named in the link. (Post from 2008, IIRC.)

I hunted around Meta for similar questions and found some, but not similar enough. It's not a [skipped review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307248/is-it-possible-to-revisit-skipped-reviews); it's a review I actually approved. And I don't simply want to [withdraw my edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287623/withdraw-suggested-edit); I found a better edit to supply in its place. I can find the item; however, all I can do is see that I have approved that review; I can't take it back (and supply a better link I found to the content referred to in the post).

Is there a way to redo an edit I reviewed? I'm mildly worried about having my reviews audited by <strike>an audit-bot</strike> a mod and found guilty of high crimes. Or even found not-guilty by mistake (the link goes *somewhere*, so a bot checking for dead links wouldn't detect it).

Comment: audits aren't done AFTER review. Audits are offered as tests INSTEAD of reviews. What you mean with your worry is you are worried a diamond mod will see the edit and enforce a ban after it (this is possible, the auditing after the edit isn't).

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Allow users to change their decisions in the review queues in case of misclicked Approve, or confirm approvals](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268567/allow-users-to-change-their-decisions-in-the-review-queues-in-case-of-misclicked)

Comment: Pretty close, aye. Didn't think to search on "misclick". I dropped a comment there.

Comment: @Patrice: ah, didn't know that. Well, I imagine a manual ban is unlikely. :-) I'm primarily concerned that I can't make that answer better.

Comment: @PaulBrinkley so I am not 100% sure, but I do believe that you will have to wait till the edit reaches it's normal conclusion since you have already reviewed it. Normally I would say you can "reject & edit" then make your change. I am not sure if you are allowed to do that once you approved the edit (my guess is not). If I am right, the only thing left is to wait for the edit to meet its end-resolution in the Review queue, then you should be able to just put your edit in. But yeah bans after a review is when a moderator sees a wrong review and enforces a manual ban

Answer (score 8):

No, but you can re-edit when review is done.

Be more careful next time.